# MySQL Use GROUP_CONCAT with Multiple JOINS

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, group-concat

I have the following four tables. My query is working correctly with the exception that I need to have the field 'AUTHORIZED_VIEWER' and 'AUTHORIZED_VIEWER_EMAIL' return all values not just the first one. I believe that this can be done by using GROUP_CONCAT, however, I am not sure exactly how this part should be implemented. *Note - when attempting to use GROUP_CONCAT, I had to use the following syntax as it was return a BLOB:*

```
CONVERT(GROUP_CONCAT(authorized_viewer) USING utf8)
```

Here are the four tables:

```
users_tbl
+-----+------------------+
|id   |email             |  
+-----+------------------+
|10   | scott@co.com     |
|8    | cesar@co.com     |
|11   | kevin@co.com     |
|12   | jake@co.com      |
+-----+------------------+

authorized_viewers_tbl (authorized_viewer linked to id in users_tbl)
+-----+------------+------------------+
|id   |lightbox_id |authorized_viewer |   
+-----+------------+------------------+
|1    | 50         |11                |
|7    | 50         |8                 |
|3    | 31         |11                |
|5    | 30         |8                 |
|6    | 30         |11                |
|8    | 16         |11                |
|9    | 16         |10                |
|10   | 5          |10                |
|11   | 5          |11                |
+-----+------------+------------------+

lightboxes_tbl
+-----+------------------+---------------+
|id   |lightbox_name     |author         |   
+-----+------------------+---------------+
|5    | Test Lightbox #1 |jake@co.com    |
|16   | Test Lightbox #2 |cesar@co.com   |
|30   | Test Lightbox #3 |scott@co.com   |
|31   | Test Lightbox #4 |kevin@co.com   |
|50   | Test Lightbox #5 |cesar@co.com   |
+-----+------------------+---------------+

lightbox_assets_tbl
+-------+-------------+------------------+------------------=---+----------+
|id     |lightbox_id  |asset_name        |asset_path            | asset_id |
+-------+-------------+------------------+----------------------+----------+
|232    |30           |b757.jpg          |SWFs/b757.jpg         | 3810     |
|230    |31           |b757.jpg          |SWFs/b757.jpg         | 3810     |
|233    |16           |a321_takeoff.jpg  |SWFs/a321_takeoff.jpg | 3809     |
|234    |31           |a321_takeoff.jpg  |SWFs/a321_takeoff.jpg | 3809     |
|235    |50           |a330_landing.png  |SWFs/a330_landing.png | 3789     |
+-------+-------------+------------------+-----------------------+---------+
```

Here's the query that I am currently using:

```
SELECT lb.id,
   lb.lightbox_name,
   lb.author,
   avt.authorized_viewer,
   u.email AS authorized_viewer_email,
   COUNT(lba.lightbox_id) total_assets
FROM lightboxes_tbl lb
LEFT JOIN lightbox_assets_tbl lba ON lb.id = lba.lightbox_id
LEFT JOIN authorized_viewers_tbl avt ON avt.lightbox_id = lb.id
LEFT JOIN users_tbl u ON u.id = avt.authorized_viewer
WHERE lb.author = 'scott@co.com'
  OR avt.authorized_viewer =
    (SELECT id
     FROM users_tbl
     WHERE email = 'scott@co.com')
GROUP BY lb.id
ORDER BY lb.lightbox_name ASC
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f3d7/1)

Thanks!

[EDIT]
Expected results based upon SQL Fiddle:

```
 +-------+----------------+--------------+-------------------+--------------------------+--------------+
 |id     |lightbox_name   |author        |authorized_viewer  | email                    | total_assets |
 +-------+----------------+--------------+-------------------+--------------------------+--------------+
 |5      |Test Lightbox#1 |jake@co.com   |10,11              |scott@co.com,kevin@co.com |0             |             
 |16     |Test Lightbox#2 |cesar@co.com  |10,11              |scott@co.com,kevin@co.com |1             |
 |30     |Test Lightbox#3 |scott@co.com  |11,8               |kevin@co.com,cesar@co.com |1             |
 +-------+-------------+-----------------+-------------------+--------------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: @xQbert That is very close. For the rows, where 'scott@co.com' is not the author, but an authorized_viewer, it's only listing scott@co.com. If possible, I need it to list all authorized_viewers, where scott@co.com is one of them. Does that make sense?  Thanks!

Comment: Yea, I think your first try was closer. So what I am expecting is that any lightbox where 'scott@co.com' is the author be returned including ALL authorized_viewers (along with all other info listed -which appears to be correct). Additionally, any lightbox where 'scott@co.com' is an authorized_viewer be returned including other authorized_viewers. A user can be an author or authorized_viewer, but not both at the same time. Hope this helps. Thanks for the continued assistance.

Comment: I was looking off of this fiddle, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f3d7/6/0, and it listed two assets for lb #30 - I am not sure why though. Anyway, I just looked at your updated fiddle and I believe that it's correct!!! Thanks for your help. If you want to create an answer, I will mark it correct.

Comment: Okay, I was able to duplicate it. Take a look at this SQL Fiddle -http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ccc6a/1, last row - LB #31. There are duplicate entries for A & B columns.

Comment: The simple way is to add distinct to the group by.  `group_concat(distinct avt.authorized_viewer) a, group_concat(distinct u.email) b,`  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ccc6a/2/0   The distinct is needed.  it's due to the double entry in lightbox_assets_tbl that we need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a cleaner way of doing this but I haven't had the time to think it though yet.

A fun question never the less thanks for sharing and hope we helped!

1. We add `group_concat` to `avt.authorized_viewer` and `u.email`
2. We add `distinct` to the `group_concat` to only pull back Unique values as requested.
3. We added `group by` for each of the non-aggregated values.
4. We altered the where clause to pull in all light boxes which Scott was a reviewer.  By using the author field as the limit we excluded the other reviewers.  By basing the filter on the Id of the lightbox, we keep all users; which allows `group_concat` to work as desired.

.

```
SELECT lb.id,
       lb.lightbox_name,
       lb.author,
       group_concat(distinct avt.authorized_viewer) a,
       group_concat(distinct u.email) b,
       COUNT(distinct lba.id) total_assets
FROM lightboxes_tbl lb
LEFT JOIN lightbox_assets_tbl lba ON lb.id = lba.lightbox_id
LEFT JOIN authorized_viewers_tbl avt ON avt.lightbox_id = lb.id
LEFT JOIN users_tbl u ON u.id = avt.authorized_viewer
where lb.author = 'scott@co.com'
or 
lb.id in (Select lightbox_ID 
          from authorized_Viewers_tbl X
          INNER JOIN users_Tbl U on U.ID = X.authorized_Viewer
          WHERE email = 'scott@co.com')
GROUP BY lb.id, lb.lightbox_name, lb.author
ORDER BY lb.lightbox_name ASC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ccc6a/2/0
Hope this wraps things up for you!  (purged several comments from base topic as I've now included them or the information garnered here.)

Comment: I am by no means anywhere near a SQL expert, so if there's a cleaner way to write this and you have time to do it, I would love to see it.  Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
SELECT lb.id,
   lb.lightbox_name,
   lb.author,
   avt.authorized_viewer,
   u.email AS authorized_viewer_email,
   COUNT(lba.lightbox_id) total_assets
FROM lightboxes_tbl lb
LEFT JOIN lightbox_assets_tbl lba ON lb.id = lba.lightbox_id
LEFT JOIN authorized_viewers_tbl avt ON avt.lightbox_id = lb.id
LEFT JOIN users_tbl u ON u.id = avt.authorized_viewer
WHERE lb.author = 'scott@co.com'
OR avt.authorized_viewer =
(SELECT id
 FROM users_tbl
 WHERE email = 'scott@co.com')
GROUP BY lb.id, lb.lightbox_name, lb.author, avt.authorized_viewer, u.email
ORDER BY lb.lightbox_name
```